# Query string encapsulated in a single object does not generate a valid Spring HATEOAS link

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am writing a Spring-boot HATEOAS web service that looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/task", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public PagedResources<Resource<Dto>> doTask(@Valid Request request, Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<Dto> assembler) {
    Page<Dto> data = service.doTask(request.getParam1(), request.getParam2(), pageable);
    Link link = linkTo(methodOn(MyController.class).doTask(request, pageable, assembler)).withSelfRel();
    return assembler.toResource(data, link);
}
```

The query string is encapsulated in the *request* object rather than having long method signature like:

```
public PagedResources<Resource<Dto>> doTask(@RequestParam String param1,@RequestParam String param2, [...], Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<Dto> assembler)
```

When the link is constructed with *linkTo* and *methodOn* in the last case the links are generated properly. However, when the query string is encapsulated in a single object, **the link is built without parameters**. Is there a way to build a link with encapsulated parameters in an object?

I tried unsuccessfully the next things:

- Annotating the *Request* object with *@ModelAttribute*
- Without *methodOn*, manually constructing a map with the parameters

In both cases the parameters are ignored.

**UPDATE:**

I am using Spring-boot 2.0.0

Comment: Did you made any further success? I still have execatly the same problem.